# Why do bluetooth speakers reconnect to device that is off?

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth

I have several bluetooth speakers, and more than 2 iOS devices. Once a speaker is paired with one iOS device (iPhone, for ex.), the next time I turn on the speaker, it connects (with beep sound) to that device again, even if that device is OFF, preventing it from connecting to a different iOS device I'm trying to use it with (iPad, for example -also previously paired with the speaker). I'm wondering if the latest Bluetooth specification has eliminated this annoying trate.

Comment: That would be technically not possible, unless the device was not off but in sleep mode.

Comment: I should have said in Sleep mode. iPad's and iPhones are almost always in sleep mode when not being used, and "awake" enough to recieve push mail, and other notifications from other sources, so it must be possible.

Comment: In that case turn off the BT.

Comment: I have the same problem. It started after upgrading to Yosemite. My MacBook reconnects to my Logitech 980-000560 BT audio adapter even when I explicitly disconnect and keeps the connection even while in sleep mode. I have to disable bluetooth or unpair the device in order for it to stop. It's annoying, because most of the time I don't want it to connect. It worked correctly on Mavericks.