# How do I keep a MacBook Air from connecting to a Bluetooth speaker when its lid is closed?

Tags: sleep-wake, bluetooth

The MacBook Air automatically connects to a (previously paired) Bluetooth speaker even when the lid is closed, which prevents the device I'm actually using at the moment from connecting to the speaker.

How do I configure the MacBook Air to **not** automatically connect to a bluetooth speaker when the lid is closed? I want everything to work as-is when the lid is open.

Comment: Related question concerning iOS: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177205/why-do-bluetooth-speakers-reconnect-to-device-that-is-off?rq=1

Answer (score 12):

Building on other answers and giving most/all puzzle pieces but not a whole solution:

1. Make sure to check if you want to have Bluetooth devices wake your Mac

   - If you don't want that, uncheck it in system preferences and check if the undesired behaviour persist (It's in `Bluetooth` → `Advanced…` → `Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer`)
2. If you need/want to wake your Mac by Bluetooth devices or this keeps happening despite turning off the option follow these steps:

Install a helper program to check for system sleep (if you want to distinguish only lid open/closed without the Mac sleeping, it seems there is currently no easy way – i.e. I didn't find out how to detect that), and toggle Bluetooth depending on sleep/wake events.

### Helpers to detect sleep/wake (check the various options in this post):

#### [Possible to run scripts on sleep and wake?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27036)

See also this post about "[Automatically turn bluetooth on or off depending on current network (MBP running Lion)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/33844)" mentioning [ControlPlane](https://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/)

### Toggle bluetooth from scripts:

#### [How to control Bluetooth wireless radio from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/47503)

My recommendation: install [blueutil](http://braumeister.org/formula/blueutil) via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Run `blueutil power 0` upon sleep

And `blueutil power 1` upon wake

Now about my contribution to this problem: If power nap causes a wake event try this script for wake to distinguish between other wake reasons and lid opening:

```
#!/bin/bash
limitSec=3
currentEpoch=$(date "+%s")
wakeEpoch=$(cat /var/log/system.log | grep LidOpen | tail -n 1 | date -j -f "%b %d %T" "$(cut -c1-15)" "+%s")
wakeSeconds=$(( $currentEpoch - $wakeEpoch ))

if [[ $wakeSeconds -lt $limitSec ]]; then
    logger "Enabling bluetooth again due to lid open"
    blueutil power 1
fi
```

It sets a timeout of 3 seconds (limitSec), gets the current time and the last time of wake with `Wake reason: EC.lidOpen`, and if that was less than 3 seconds ago it will re-enable Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @iolsmit, I created a script that downloads and configures `blueutil` and `sleepwatcher` to disable bluetooth when the machine goes to sleep, then re enables when the machine wakes up.

https://github.com/alb12-la/KBOS

Just download homebrew, then run `bash setup.sh` from the repo directory.